# how to parse image inside the Json array in windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, json, url, windows-phone-8

I followed How to parse json data from url in windows phone from [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/06/23/10425845.aspx) and [this link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Listbox_handling_in_Windows_Phone)

But i have this kind of JSON data..

```
{
 "returnCode": "success",
  "Data": {
  "results": [
    {
        "moredetails": [
            {
                "newoffers": [

                ],
                "recentoffers_count": 0,
                "sku": "30072246"
            },
            {
                "newoffers": [
                    {
                        "availability": "Available",
                        "currency": "USD"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "newoffers": [
                    {
                        "availability": "Available",
                        "currency": "USD"
                    }
                ],
                "offers_count": 1,
                "name": "google.com"
            }
        ],
        ..."features": {
            ..
        },
        "length": "20",
        "geo": [
            "usa"
        ],
        .."images": ["http://timenerdworld.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/wpid-photo-jan-14-2013-1117-am.jpg"],
        ..
    }
],
...
}
}
```

My problem is that i have image inside the JSONArray..

Similarly for this kind in java(android) i done..
parsing like this..

```
JSONArray images = c.getJSONArray("images");
                for(int s=0;s<images.length();s++)
                {
                    map.put("images", images.getString(s));
                 }
```

After that its worked fine in android ..

Now in C#..
i done Parsing By `get,set`methoid..
But at here image is inside the JSONarray

I am using image loader functionality like this..

```
ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(root1.Data.results.images));
StackPanelBackground.Background = imageBrush;
```

as i know that codes for only this kind..

> "images":"http://timenerdworld.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/wpid-photo-jan-14-2013-1117-am.jpg"

not for this kind

> "images": ["http://timenerdworld.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/wpid-photo-jan-14-2013-1117-am.jpg"]

In C# what should i need to change to display image..

In windows Phone 8 i am parsing json By this way..

```
    public class Moredetail
{
public List[object] newoffers { get; set; }
public int recentoffers_count { get; set; }
public string sku { get; set; }
public int? offers_count { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
public List [Moredetail] moredetails { get; set; }
public string length { get; set; }
public List[string] geo { get; set; }
public List[string] images { get; set; }
}

public class Data 
{
public List[Result] results { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
 public string returnCode { get; set; }
 public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

i follow this for [Displaying image and parsing json](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/06/23/10425845.aspx)

I am getting data from a server.. and i already done this on android i want to build same in windows phone 8..
Any Sugession

Comment: So, you are getting `"images":["http` instead of `"images":"http`, right ?

Comment: yes crea7or sir.. in android i found a way to display that image but in windows phone 7/8 i want to display it.. and is there any other way  to parse this kind of json data in java we have nearly 8 methods but in windows phone in c# i found only two but i know about this(get,set) very well.. if any example let me know sir..

Comment: So, why not to remove braces?

Comment: how can i remove i am getting this data from a server.. i con't change the server.. and one more thing in android i already done this app from same server.. same json array.. am asking that how we can do this in c# (windows phone)

Answer (score 2):

Using JSON.NET you can get the array of images like

```
var j = JObject.Parse(yourJsonString);
var images = (JArray)j.SelectToken("results").SelectToken("images");
```

and the first image is

```
var firstImageUrl = images.First().ToString();
```

so then you can use

```
mageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(firstImageUrl));
StackPanelBackground.Background = imageBrush;
```

Comment: thak you sir But is it works on this code..http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/06/23/10425845.aspx sir... i tried But its not working please help me sir,,

Comment: hi can you please give me in this kind of example.. http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Listbox_handling_in_Windows_Phone ........ You have Given that var j = JObject.Parse(yourJsonString);
var images = (JArray)j.SelectToken("results").SelectToken("images"); for java parsed code.. even though its is in C#.. i not implemented var j = JObject.Parse in C#,.. In C# i done this by Get,set.. Please check my updated question.. sir.. Thank you i hope you will hel me./..

Comment: if images is a list, why dont you just use root1.Data.results.images[0]?

Comment: sorry  Igor Kulman sir i dont know any other method of image inside json array..if there let me know or just any example.. and one more thing sir i implemented code according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/06/23/10425845.aspx  and   http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Listbox_handling_in_Windows_Phone so i am not using var j = JObject.Parse(yourJsonString);..